# Icon not changing in ajax success handler

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax, flask

I'm trying to make a function 'add to my list' in my web application. 
When user clicks on an icon, this fuction should change the color of the icon after sending data to server.

It doesn't throw any errors, it sends data to server successfully, but it never changes the icon. 'console.log' inside ajax success handler is working fine, so what is the problem here?

Thanks in advance!

```
<div class="buttons">
  <button type="button" class="btn threeButtons" onclick="request_access(this)" id="{{ elem['isbn'].split()[0] }}">
     <i class="fas fa-plus"></i>
  </button>
</div>
```

```
function request_access($this){
    console.log("button clicked");
    var request_data = $this.id;
    var me = $(this);

    $.ajax({
        url: "/admin_add_books",
        type: "POST",
        data: request_data,
        success: function(){
            console.log("data: " + request_data)
            me.find('i').addClass('green');
            }
        })
}
```

Comment: What does green clsss do?
Also there is an extra 's' at the end of your i tag

Comment: Just fyi...when your listener gets called, it gets the *element* reference. When you do $(this) instead of $($this), that's what's throwing it off. You want `$($this)`. But, I'd prefer to just rename that argument to something like "elm", which refers to the button element.

Comment: See this for an example: https://jsfiddle.net/9sv8wmtg/

Comment: Oh no I feel like an idiot.. I got confused with font awesome with bootstrap, and thought adding class would change the color. Thanks for pointing it out! (Also I deleted 's' on my post)

Comment: It works beautifully!!! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do sthg just after data is sent but response is not sent from server, then you should do sthg like:

```
var response = $.ajax({
        url: "/admin_add_books",
        type: "POST",
        data: request_data
    });
// Change color just after data is sent
me.children("i").addClass("green");

response.done(function(result){
    // Server returned result
    me.children("i").addClass("green");
});
```

*Note:- success is depreciated in modern version of jquery. [Link](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)